# Add Button to UIWebView InputAccessoryView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I just want to be able to add a button to a UIWebView's InputAccessoryView.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd like to keep the existing buttons but add one more that will activate a camera barcode scanner.

Comment: Did you ever find out?? These answers are not good.. most don't understand the question

Comment: @DanMoore I ended up using a UIToolbar. Normally I would use this https://github.com/rexfinn/RFKeyboardToolbar but I needed a way to keep the existing buttons, which no one seemed to understand...

Answer (score 0):

You button links should look like this:

```
<a href="button://dosomething" class="buttonStyle">Click me!</a>
```

We are using a custom protocol we make up: button://.

Now implement shouldStartLoadWithRequest like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    // only do something if a link has been clicked...
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {     

            // check if the url requests starts with our custom protocol:
        if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"button://"]) {
            // Do custom code
            return NO;
        } 
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourSelector)]];
[toolbar sizeToFit];
[self.webView.inputAccessoryView addSubview:toolbar];
```

Please tell me if this works.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: No I am not using storyboards.